# Send array values in PHP form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a HTML form with embedded PHP code that creates a checkbox for each value contained in an array. Just like this:

```
<?php 
  $rows = array_map( 'str_getcsv', file( 'file.csv' ) );
  $header = array_shift( $rows );
  foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="'.$row[0].'" name="'.$row[0].'">
          <label for="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</label>
          <input type="number" name="'.$row[0].'" placeholder="Some text">';
  }
?>
```

Now, I want to send this form using this code, which is inserted into another PHP file:

```
<?php
  if( isset( $_POST ) == true && empty( $_POST ) == false ) {
    $account = $_POST['account'];
    $investment = $_POST['row[0]'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $formcontent=" Account: $account \n $row[0]: $investment \n Password: $password";
    $recipient = "my@email.com";
    $subject = "My Form";
    $mailheader = "From: My Form <my@form.com>";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Some text";
  } 
?>
```

But it doesn't work. When you click on submit button the form does nothing.

I've checked it with success with HTML-only code, so I guess I'm making a mistake with PHP.

**For those interested, here's a link to my form:** [Example](http://s649883118.mialojamiento.es)

**EDIT**: I've removed `preventDefault`, as pointed by @DavidJorHpan, but I'm still stuck. I'm unable to make my form.php send `$row[0]` to my email.

Comment: what is the error code? Now you explain a little more?

Comment: Can you give us the error you're getting.

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz I've updated my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JakeSylvestre Please see Comment #3.

Comment: You are using the name attribute wrong. Use it like this `name="operative[]"` then use `value` attribute to set the actual value

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `preventDefault` so it will never submit form until you code for submitting form

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can remove that code or add code like
    `$('form').submit();`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing your point, but I didn't use `preventDefault`.

Comment: you used in your `index.js`

Comment: It works, but I'm still stuck. Please check new post edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As David JorHpan pointed out in the second answer, you've got to remove preventDefault() from the button click event. That prevents the form from being submitted.

For every checkbox you have a corresponding number input field. Although possible, its not a good practice to have spaces in your 'name' attribute values. Try replacing those spaces with dashes or underscores. For example you can do something like below:

```
name="'.str_replace(' ','_',$row[0]).'"
```

and same can be done to id attribute values.

Your form submit check should work but it will make more sense if you change that as follows:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   // process here
}
```

After doing these changes try loading the page and see how it goes.

Comment: It works, but I'm still stuck. Please check new post edit. Thanks.

Comment: @ÁngelNarciso Please fix your name attribute on input fields. Are you looking to get multiple values or just a single value out of those check boxes?